# ClientDisconnected due to error: Timeout e Ready with no player

Tags: c#, unity-5, timeout

Olá, estou com um problema de conexão em meu projeto multiplayer. Ao criar uma partida local, tudo parece funcionar bem, porém, o console mostra os seguintes avisos [image: Ready with no player object e playerControllerId: 0]

quando eu faço uma build e crio a partida pelo celular, e tento entrar nela pelo computador (que está na mesma rede), eu recebo um erro de **timeout**

[image: Client disconnected due to error timeout]

Eu já tentei de tudo, porém o problema persiste. Aparentemente esse bug pode estar na **criação de um host para a partida**.

Aqui está o script que eu estou usando na criação da partida:

```cs
﻿using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NetworkManager_Custom : NetworkManager {

    public void StartupHost(){
        SetPort();
        NetworkManager.singleton.StartHost();
    }

    public void JoinGame(){

        SetIPAdress();
        SetPort();
        NetworkManager.singleton.StartClient();

    }

    public void SetIPAdress(){

        string ipAdress = GameObject.Find("ipInputField").transform.Find("Text").GetComponent<Text>().text;
        NetworkManager.singleton.networkAddress = ipAdress;
    }

    public void SetPort(){

        NetworkManager.singleton.networkPort = 7777;

    }

}
```

Comment: Ao que tudo indica, a aplicação está aguardando solicitações locais (127.0.0.1), justifica o local funcionar, então a partir de outro IP, não é possível. Procure por expor a aplicação para todos IPs: 0.0.0.0

Comment: Infelizmente, nenhum IP parece ter funcionado, nem mesmo substituindo o ip local 127.0.0.1 por localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pelas respostas! Consegui resolver esse problema da seguinte maneira:
1- No Network Manager, existe a possibilidade de mudar o IP preferencial da engine.
2- Lá você precisa colocar o endereço ip do host da partida, que poderá ser encontrado no comando "ipconfig" no cmd.

Agora só falta fazer a engine encontrar automaticamente o ip do host da partida e conectar nele.

Answer (score -1):

Olá,

Tentar mudar a porta para outra. Algo como 1616 e veja também se seu firewall está ativado. Pode ser isso.

Tenta controlar a conexão com o log em caso de falhas.

veja esse exemplo em https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/Manual/UNetManager.html

Comment: Olá, no caso da porta do servidor, eu já alterei pra outras que aparentemente não estavam sendo usadas. Quanto ao log, eu mudei o display do log para Info, por isso estão sendo mostradas as informações de conexão no console.

Como eu disse anteriormente, o problema parece estar na seleção de um host para a partida.